# qbittorrent-nox on fedora server: no remote web ui access

Tags: linux, fedora, qbittorrent

I've installed qbittorent-nox on my fedora server and started it remotely via ssh. Now I want to access the web ui remotely, but my webbrowser won't connect.

Is remote access disabled by default for qbittorrent-nox? The log file suggest that it is not only listening on localhost, but on its IP address.

Or is fedora blocking the web ui? Do I have to enable it in the firewall or something? New fedora user here...

Answer (score 0):

My hunch about the firewall was actually correct. And opening the port was easy:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=8080/tcp
```

Now I can access the qbittorrent web ui remotely.